# Add image for readmore drop down

Tags: javascript, css

I want to know how to add drop down image for this script.

```
 <a onclick="showMoreOrLess(this,'restOfArticle');">+Sign In </a>
 <span id="restOfArticle" style="display:none"> </span>
```

Script

```
<script>function showMoreOrLess(thisObj, bonusContent) {
var caption = thisObj.innerHTML;
//alert(caption);
if (caption == "+Sign In") {
    document.getElementById(bonusContent).style.display = "inline";
    thisObj.innerHTML = "-Sign In";
} else {
    document.getElementById(bonusContent).style.display = "none";
    thisObj.innerHTML = "+Sign In";
}
}
</script>
```

I want to replace + and - with small image icon, how do do it?

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `+` or `-` sign. Add a class to the anchor and then use `:before` pseudo selector.

**HTML**

```
<a class="icon-left" onclick="showMoreOrLess(this,'restOfArticle');">Sign In </a>
```

**CSS**

```
.icon-left::before {
  content: url('Icon image URL here');
}
```

Comment: Thanks you manoj., any other way to add two icons like up and down arrow when collapse?